# How to create two different images for mobile and desktop browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

I'm trying to add javascript on top of my page and if it detects mobile browser then my html code will use the appropriate html code and image **height** and **width** settings.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) )
    <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B2VHnnIsISjHdWRLVk9zS2VuUFk" alt="" style="width:1904px;height:328px;">
  else
    <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B2VHnnIsISjHdWRLVk9zS2VuUFk" alt="" style="width:1904px;height:528px;">
</script>
```

I am not sure why its not working?

how do i make this in full javascript

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
  img.src = "http://home.bt.com/images/the-iphone-7-and-7-plus-which-bt-mobile-plan-is-right-for-me-136409622203503901-160915131847.jpg";
  img.style.width = "648px";
  img.style.height = "365px";
} else {
  img.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d7/Desktop_computer_clipart_-_Yellow_theme.svg/281px-Desktop_computer_clipart_-_Yellow_theme.svg.png";
  img.style.width = "281px";
  img.style.height = "203px";
}
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

so its in

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

some code

## like this full code so i can add it to my html code

**edited new**

is this correct ?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var img = document.createElement("img");
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
  img.src = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B2VHnnIsISjHdWRLVk9zS2VuUFk";
  img.style.width = "1904px";
  img.style.height = "365px";
} else {
  img.src = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B2VHnnIsISjHdWRLVk9zS2VuUFk";
  img.style.width = "1904px";
  img.style.height = "403px";
}
document.body.appendChild(img);

        </script>
```

Comment: You can't write HTML tags in your JavaScript. See @Yusaf Khaliq answer.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly you want to show 1 of 2 images depending if the user is on a mobile or computer. (btw i have not tested your test function)

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    img.src = src;
    img.style.width = width;
    img.style.height = height;
    }
    else{
    img.src = src;
    img.style.width = width;
    img.style.height = height;
    }
document.body.appendChild(img);
    </script>
```

first you can create the image node, set the src height and width and then append to the body. also there is room to clean up the code I have used in my example. set the style width and height outside the if else blocks for e.g.

Comment: how do i set the hieght and width boss

Comment: how do i also add link to image src

Comment: change `img.src = "link to image here"`; and `image.style.width = "100px"`

Comment: both image are same problem is when i set the height of 433 then on pc it looks fine but when using mobile browser it is to large , so this is why am trying to detect if it is mobile browser if then use the correct hight for it

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rxff2qoq/ in this exmaple, if the browser is on mobile it will show a mobile image, if a computer an image of a computer.

Comment: ok don't set the image to a fixed "px" set it to relative width using either "%" or "em". I would go with % as it's easier. set width to "100%" using image.style.width = "100%"

Comment: can u check the 1st post i added your code, if u can kindly show me the full javascript code so i can add it to my page to test it live please boss

Comment: can u check my 1st post again last one i added ?

Comment: can u check my 1st post again last one i added ?, i added this to my post its not showing up the image maybe i done it wrong ?

Comment: the 100% should be in quotes like "100%". it's a string. also if you used "100%" width do not set the height, the browser will automatically take care of the height.

Comment: i think this is wrong <script type="text/javascript">

Comment: am trying to add <script type="text/javascript"> then your code inside this but its not working , maybe <script type="text/javascript"> needs to be in some format ?

Comment: after the code you have to close the tag using </script>

Comment: yup i have if u check 1st post last one it has it , but my wordpress its not outputting it

Comment: I can't help you beyond here unfortunately, I can not go through every option to see why it is not working. please use the jsfiddle links i have provided to reference.

Comment: if u test it here also https://jsbin.com/qoyoseguda/edit?html,output   its not showing

Comment: js fiddler working but how do i make it work in html as full javascript?

Comment: i ran the whole code again on this website https://js.do/    and it says ×
JavaScript error: TypeError: document.body is null on line 15

Comment: heres the new one https://jsbin.com/votowadidu/edit?html,output . it't because you are using the javascript in the head. the body hasnt rendered.

Comment: its working  but it puts it in my footer of the site how come

Comment: i have a specific bannera area where i add html code and i want it to appear their instead it goes to footer area all the way bottom of the site